# Confused about relationship between electric and magnetic field for time harmonic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

My E&M professor's powerpoint says,[image]

where $\eta$ is impedance.

I know that the the E and H fields are perpendicular to each other, so it makes sense that we're using a cross-product, but why specifically with the unit vector in the $z$ direction, rather than the $y$ direction?  And why divide by impedance?  I would've thought that we'd need to use Faraday's law to relate the E and H fields or else integrate the E field to get voltage, then use voltage and impedance to get current and then use current in the Biot-Savart law.  I don't get how it makes any sense to just divide by impedance like that.  I mean, I'm sure if I plugged in the units and checked the dimensional analysis it would work out, but I wouldn't really get where the impedance actually comes in.  If someone could help me understand, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider what direction would H point if you crossed with the vector $a_y$.

Comment: @Triatticus, it would point in the -z direction.  That would still be perpendicular to the x direction, so why would it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*but why specifically with the unit vector in the $\hat z$ direction, rather than the $\hat y$ direction?*
You have to start somewhere and your professor started by assuming the $\hat z$ direction.

Because [impedance](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Physical_Optics_(Tatum)/02%3A_Reflection_and_Transmission_at_Boundaries_and_the_Fresnel_Equations/2.05%3A_Impedance) is defined as $E_0/H_0$ and found to be a useful parameter and for free space has a value of $\sqrt{\epsilon_0/\mu_0}$.
Note that in general impedance has both real and imaginary components.

[The Derivation of Intrinsic Impedance](https://resources.system-analysis.cadence.com/blog/msa2021-the-derivation-of-intrinsic-impedance) may be an article of interest although the choice of directions differ from that of your professor.